# No Camera option found in config file

Tags: camera

I have tried everything I have read about this issue found on the internet, but still nothing from the camera works and the options still do not show up in my config file.

I am a newbie to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Which OS? Which camera? Which Pi? Which config file?